# Why do function pointers break substitutability and std::function doesn't?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, liskov-substitution-principle

We have an usual class hierarchy:

```
class B
{
public:
    int x;
    B() : x(0) {}
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    int y;
    D() : y(0) {}
};
```

And a function that takes one argument - reference to a base class object.

```
void b_set(B& b)
{
    b.x = 5;
}
```

Then, I want to create function pointer of type `void (D&)` and store `b_set` in it. This should be valid operation, as all objects legally passed to function pointer call must be also of type B. Yet it isn't allowed.

```
typedef void (*fp_d_mutator)(D&);
void fp_test(D& obj)
{
    fp_d_mutator fun = b_set; //invalid conversion from 'void (*)(B&)' to 'fp_d_mutator {aka void (*)(D&)}
    fun(obj);
}

#include <functional>
typedef std::function<void (D&)> stdfun_d_mutator;
void stdfun_test(D& obj)
{
    stdfun_d_mutator fun = b_set; //works 
    fun(obj);
}
```

So...

- How is that invalid conversion?
- Why is that invalid conversion?
- What could break if this was allowed?
- How std::function avoids the problem in the first place?

Comment: which compiler and version does the "works" apply to

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf g++ 4.7.2 MinGW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function that takes an argument of type `B&` is not a function that takes an argument of type `D&`. While `D&` is **convertible to** `B&`, they are not the same type. If you could store a pointer to a function that takes `B&` as a pointer to `D&`, how would the compiler know when to convert the argument? (Note that the conversion sometimes requires adjusting a pointer)

The difference in `std::function` is that the calling signature (here `D&`) is part of the function object's type, **and** the called signature (here `B&`) is part of the internal storage. So when you apply the function objects' `operator()` the code that implements `operator()(D&)` takes care of the conversion.

Comment: Oh, that's right, forgot about pointer adjustment. So apart from calling the stored function, std::function also calls the necessary conversions. Yeah, the answer is satisfying, but I'll wait a moment before accepting.

Comment: @milleniumbug - yes, pretty much. The function call operator doesn't do any conversions explicitly; when the callable object (in this case a pointer to function) was stored into the `std::function` object the assignment operator stored the type information as well. Calling the callable object is just like calling a "normal" function: `void f(float); int i; f(i);`. No explicit conversion, but the compiler adjusts types as necessary.